# ¿Cómo usar el Test χ² para seleccionar las características que pueden ser String o categóricas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

Quiero estadísticas para seleccionar las características que tienen la mayor relación con la variable de salida.

Gracias a [este articulo](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e), apprendi que la biblioteca de `scikit-learn` propone la clase `SelectKBest` que puede utilizarse con un conjunto de diferentes pruebas estadísticas para seleccionar un número específico de características.

Aqui esta mi dataframe:

```
    Do you agree    Gender  Age     City     Urban/Rural  Output
0   Yes             Female  25-34   Madrid   Urban        Will buy
1   No              Male    18-25   Valencia Rural        Won't
2   ...             ...     ...     ...      ...          Undecided
....
```

El output esta `Will buy`, `won't` and `undecided`.

Entonces intenté la prueba estadística de chi-cuadrado (chi²) para las características no negativas para seleccionar 10 de las mejores características:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

data = pd.read_csv("D://Blogs//train.csv")
X = data.iloc[:,0:20]  #independent columns
y = data.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range#apply SelectKBest class to extract top 10 best features
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
#concat two dataframes for better visualization 
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
featureScores.columns = ['Specs','Score']  #naming the dataframe columns
print(featureScores.nlargest(10,'Score'))  #print 10 best features
```

Pero ciertas columnas son `String`. Entonces, me devuelve el terminal:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-e64d61febefd> in <module>
      1 bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2,k=10)
----> 2 fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
      3 dfscores = pd.Dataframes(X.columns)
      4 #concat two dataframes for better visualization
      5 featuresScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores], axis = 1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py in fit(self, X, y)
    339         self : object
    340         """
--> 341         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'], multi_output=True)
    342 
    343         if not callable(self.score_func):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    754                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    755                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 756                     estimator=estimator)
    757     if multi_output:
    758         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    565         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    566         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 567             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    568         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    569             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Yes, I agree'
```

Answer (score 0):

utiliza labelencoder para codificar las variables de cadena o one hot encoding. Un saludo

Comment: Cómo podría usarlo? Procura añadir alguna explicación breve de cómo podría el OP usar tu recomendación en su código, sin que sea necesariamente un ejemplo detallado.